Sort the layers of objects in a scrollview
I'm working on a personal project to make a website with the Unity UGUI.
I'm using a Scrollview which has a vertical layout group and a Content fitter component. It has several containers as children, like the picture below.

I put a calendar in the second container. I want the calendar to be visible above the containers when I click the calendar button. Like in the picture below.
The result I want.

So I used the three methods below.

Add a Layer to put it on top of the other containers.
Use a Sorting Layer to put it on top of other containers.
Usea Sorting Group to set it above the other containers.

However, Unity only gave me the result shown in the photo below.

As shown in the photo, the calendar was displayed under the third container. To fix this, I created a test Canvas and moved only the calendar to the bottom of it. The calendar appeared above all the containers, just as I wanted, but there was one problem. When I scrolled, the calendar, which was supposed to be attached to the second container, stayed in place and moved separately from the scroll.
I posted a question to find a better way. If anyone can help me, please point me to a good way.

We've found the reason it doesn't look like that. I had created all of my objects as RectTransforms. I didn't realize that RectTransforms are visible to the camera in order to use the layer, but RectTransforms are visible before the camera.  So it looks like I need to find a way to break up the RectTransforms into layers to make them visible to do what I want.
PS. I realize that they are shown in the order of the dashboard, but structurally (the containers are in a ScrollView) I can't change the order.

You could look into the Source Code of Dropdown .. basically they ad-hoc instantiate a complete separate Canvas with blocker background (to close the drop-down and block other interactions) .. this other canvas they always set to render on top

The UI GameObjects in Unity are placed the from bottom to top according to their Hierarchy's positions. So in the image below, the Container 2 is going to be below the Container 3.

If you want to place the Container 2 above the Container 3, you will have have to replace them in the Hierarchy, which will also replace their positions on the screen. This, obviously, won't solve your issue.


1st half-solution - Local Canvas

Add a Canvas component on the Container 2,
Tick the Override sorting
Change the Order in layer to make it appear on top of the Container 3.


This places the Container 2 and all its children on top of the Container 3 and other Containers, as we override the sorting using a local Canvas.
You may add as many Canvases as you wish, which makes you able to e.g. place the Container 4 above the Container 7 and the Container 6 above the Container 5.

The problem is that if you have a Viewport on a Scroll Rect, which contains a Mask / Rect Mask 2D, the Container 2 won't care about it because of its Canvas.

So, I believe Unity doesn't really have a great variant to fix is, and there may be still a hard one, which includes writing a full script, and which I would've tried to implement, hadn't we had the second solution.

2nd solution - Material's render queue

The Graphic in has a material field to reference the Material used
The Material has its Render queue field, which is basically the Graphic's Order in layer

So,

Create a new Material and set its Shader to UI/Default
You can see the Render queue field
The default Render queue is Transparent, which is 3000, for all the default UI objects
Changing the value will place with the Material above the others if > 3000 and below if < 3000


Assigning the Material to all the Images of your Container 2 puts it above the other Contents.

As you may see, the text "Container" is missing. Now, we can create an another type of the Material to fix it, but it won't be possible, as we cannot really assign its Render queue like we did with the Default UI one.

So, I'd recommend you creating a few small scrips, which won't just solve the issue with the TMP_Text, but will also prevent you from creating a new Material for every different Render queue.
We won't be able to create a single script for both Graphics and TMP_Text, because even though the TMP_Text derives from the Graphics, its real Material can be accessed via TMP_Text.fontMaterial, not Graphics.material.
using UnityEngine;

[ExecuteAlways]
[DisallowMultipleComponent]
public abstract class RenderQueue : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int renderQueue;

    private Material _material;

    private void OnValidate()
    {
        _material.renderQueue = renderQueue;
    }

    protected Material GetMaterialInstance(Material material)
    {
        _material = new Material(material);

        renderQueue = _material.renderQueue;

        return _material;
    }
}

using UnityEngine.UI;

public class GraphicRenderQueue : RenderQueue
{
    private void OnEnable()
    {
        Graphic graphic = GetComponent<Graphic>();

        graphic.material = GetMaterialInstance(graphic.material);
    }
}

using TMPro;

public class TextRenderQueue : RenderQueue
{
    private void OnEnable()
    {
        TMP_Text text = GetComponent<TMP_Text>();

        text.fontMaterial = GetMaterialInstance(text.fontMaterial);
    }
}


The GraphicRenderQueue script should be added to Graphics, including Images, and TextRenderQueue to TMP_Texts.
The children of the Container 2 won't be visible if their Render queues are smaller than of their parents, so the scripts should usually be added to every of them.

This is the Scrollview, where both Container 2 and Calendar contain GraphicRenderQueue for their Images and TextRenderQueue for their TMP_Texts. It's placed above the Container 3 and doesn't have any issues with the Mask, which Container with the local Canvas had.

The scripts are just the small examples and you can easily extend their logic for your convenience if you need it.
